# Cannot login to www.messenger.com but can login to Facebook Messenger Android app

Tags: facebook-messenger, account-recovery

I installed Facebook Messenger but I do not have a "regular" profile at Facebook for privacy reasons. Now FB Messenger will not let me log in at www.messenger.com but my password is correct because I can change my password in the Android messenger app. I cannot see my phone number in FB Messenger but I tried all phone numbers I recently had. It is also impossible to delete my account from the FB Android app, it tries to force me to make a web login to regular Facebook which is an authentication I don't have or they won't let me.

Is this even legal making it impossible for a user to delete his own data? How can I proceed? Of course the "Help" and "Support" is just a waste of time and another way of not answering question.

I regret that I ever tried anything from Facebook. They are terrible!

I want to be able to use the thing normally: Install the app on several devices, and login to "my account" on www.messenger.com. am able to login to my Facebook Messenger Android app account. I can also change my password from there which proves that I know the correct password.

Comment: [Related](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/145339/88163) (no answers at this time)