# i am trying to reset my messenger password without having a Facebook account i am doing all the step with success but the process still failed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, account-recovery

Ok here is the steps that I follow.

1. First of all, I click on forgot password field.
2. In a box will pop up with the original phone number or email address you used to sign up initially, it asks me to fill-in the corrected phone number/letter of the items you listed if you know and/or remember.
3. After that, they sent me a code by text which I had to retrieve and enter into the missing portions which will open it up and allow me to reset and enter the new password.
4. After I entered the new password with success and reset it, I got redirected in the login page with a new message said "the password you have entered is incorrect please try again later"

Does the problem occurred because Facebook recently removed the option to someone to have messenger only with a phone number without having a Facebook account ?

If yes what should I do now I don't want to lose my account.

How to recover it?